# Assigning part of 2d array to a 1d array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

How do I do the following:

```
int A[2][2];
int B[2];
A[1][0]=2;
B=A[1];
printf("%d",B[0]); //prints out 2
```

must I use malloc? I know that in higher level languages the above method works, but I'm a little confused about what to do in C

Comment: `A[1]` is an array with 2 elements; B is an object ot type `int`. You cannot assign an array to a single variable: you can assign an array element (of the same type), with `B = A[1][0];`

Comment: @pmg oops forgot to indicate that B is also an array, a 1D array

Comment: What does your "prints out 2" comment mean? The code you posted is not compilable. How can it "print out" anything?

Comment: @AndreyT note that this is not a functional code, more of a pseudo-code. B=A[1] sets array B equal to the 1d array A[1]. A[1][0]=2 so B[0]=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to arrays (though you can *initialize* them, which is very different).

You can do what you want, by assigning to `B` element-by-element

```
B[0] = A[1][0];
B[1] = A[1][1];
```

or, with a loop

```
for (k=0; k<2; k++) B[k] = A[1][k];
```

Comment: are there more efficient ways to do that though? looping element by element seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: The compiler should optimize it for you ... but you can try a [`memmove`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memmove.html) or [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memcpy.html): `memmove(B, A, sizeof B);`. Remember to `#include <string.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the variable is declared as int B, when you should declare it as `int B[2]`.

In your code, when you assign `A[1]` to `B`, it assigns the value of the first element of `A[1]` to `B`

You can declare as `int *B`, so you will assign the ptr of `A[1]` to `B`. As it is, depending on the compiler will not compile. To test, do:

```
int *B;
B = A[1];
printf("%d, %d", B[0], B[1]);
```

Comment: i made the changes a few moments ago, typo, but the question remains the same as before

Comment: Above, you will have a reference to A, thus changing B, A is also changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could you memcpy().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
  int b[2];

  // Syntax: memcpy(to, from, number_of_bytes_to_copy);
  // (to and from should be pointers)
  memcpy(b, a[1], sizeof(int) * 2);

  printf("%d %d", b[0], b[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not assignable. You cannot assign the entire array. Whether it's 2D, 1D or 42D makes no difference here at all.

Use `memcpy`

```
static_assert(sizeof B == sizeof A[1]);
memcpy(B, A[1], sizeof B);
```

write your own array-copying function or use a macro

```
#define ARR_COPY(d, s, n) do{\
    size_t i_, n_; for (i_ = 0, n_ = (n); i_ < n_; ++i_) (d)[i_] = (s)[i_];\
  }while(0)

ARR_COPY(B, A[1], 2);
```

Comment: In other words: "*You no assign array to array.*" :)